# How to escape the OpenCV loop created while recording the webcam?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I need to record the webcam video while another program is running simultaneously. To achieve this I used threads and was able to run two functions which are, webcam recording and a simple tkinter window.

```py
import cv2
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

# video recording part
def capture():
    cv2.namedWindow('video', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow('video', 150, 150)

    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')
    videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('sample/sample.mp4', fourcc, 18.0, (640, 480))

    while True:
        ret, frame = capture.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('video', frame)
        videoWriter.write(frame)
    else:
        pass

    capture.release()
    videoWriter.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# simple window
def window():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x200')
    root.mainloop()

t1 = Thread(target=window, args=[])
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=capture, args=[])

while t1.is_alive():
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
```

My intention is to stop the video recording functionality when the simple window is closed. But with the above code, I am only able to start both the functions at once but not close them together. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: add a waitkey delay (just after the write frame) : if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

something like this will let you quit pressing the letter q

Comment: @UlisesBussi The suggested method causes only the webcam recording to stop. But I think that cannot be used to stop both at once.

Comment: Better running tkinter in main thread.

Comment: you can use the same if to finalize all the proceses you want: close videoCaptures, and so...  what more you need to do?